# Date is a column and Time is a Row. I cannot sync the two

Tags: python, pandas

My main problem is merging the time and date for some spreadsheets on pandas.

Introduction: I am switching from excel to pandas for data analysis. I am sent data in excel format from industrial sites. Problem is many power companies send the data with the date in columns and the the time in rows.

I am not sure how to join these. My final goal is to plot a year long plot. However, I need the times, so I can zoom in. Here is are some pictures of example data I am working with:

[Example Data in Pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B66d.png)

[Example Data in Excel "LibreOffice"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79uM2.png)

I am not sure if pandas can accept a row of times and columns of dates, then associate that with the data points. I also thought about getting the time header and transposing it repetitively as a column along with with each data row. However, I the dates columns would have to be extended as well. I was wondering if their was any functions in pandas that would make this easier? Thank you for the the help, and I apologize for my ignorance in pandas, I just started two weeks ago.

Note: My df.Date works fine, but my Df.Time does not detect the times automatically as expected. I also know how to combine date and time when they are both columns. pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])

Comment: Do not post picture of your dataframe. Copy/paste text data here.

Comment: You can use pandas `melt` to transform your dataframe to "tidy" format with 3 columns Date, Time, Value. Before using your `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas melt to transform your dataframe to **tidy** format

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2019/01/02', '2019/03/04'],
    '10:00' : [1, 2],
    '11:00' : [3, 4]
})
#          Date  10:00  11:00
# 0  2019/01/02      1      3
# 1  2019/03/04      2      4

b = a.melt(id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Time')
#          Date   Time  value
# 0  2019/01/02  10:00      1
# 1  2019/03/04  10:00      2
# 2  2019/01/02  11:00      3
# 3  2019/03/04  11:00      4
```

Then

```
pd.to_datetime(b.Date + ' ' + b.Time)
```

Comment: Glad it's helped. Please consider accept the answer : )